# Input of a value in a cell on one open Excel sheet update a value in a cell in a different sheet (same Workbook)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Complete novice with VBA and how to structure/insert code.

Want to have a value entered into a cell on Sheet1 and update (overwrite) a cell (in a 500 Row by 2000 Column spreadsheet).  Know the Row & Column position in the 500X2000 spreadsheet.  Don't know how to write the VBA code that allows me to pass the Row number, Column number and Value to update the 500X2000 spreadsheet with.

Again, complete novice here....

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like a formula to me. I don't see why you would need VBA for this. What kind of value are you entering, what kind of output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt need vba for this.

In the 500x2000 spreadsheet, find the cell which you want to update and enter the following, replacing [row] and [column] with the appropriate Number and letter.

```
=Sheet1!$[column]$[row]
```